# How do you solve $x^{\log x}=100x$

Tags: logarithms

How do you solve $x^{\log x}=100x$?

Can you please thoroughly explain the left side of the equation.

Please explain very clearly because I have only been learning logarithms for about a week.

Comment: Do you mean $x^{\log x} = 100x$?

Comment: 1.-Substitute $x=10^y$

2.- ???

3.-Profit

Comment: yes. that is what i mean

Comment: You should specify that you are using the logarithm base $10$ (It is not wrong as stated, but I suspect by the $100=10^2$ that you intended that).

Comment: if you put nothing that means it is base 10.

Comment: @user3175999 No, it means base [$e$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant))

Comment: well, we learned in class that its base 10.

Comment: @user3175999 - engineers use it to mean base $10$, mathematicians base $e$.

Comment: mathematicians: any base

Comment: @chubakueno, oh thanks, our math teacher is an engineer

Comment: sorry, i tried to edit it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take $\log$ from both sides:
$$\log \left( x^{\log x}\right)=\log(100x)$$
$$\log (x) \log (x)=\log(100x)=\log(100)+\log(x)$$
Or:
$$(\log x)^2-(\log x)=2$$
Now you have a quadratic equation which you should be able to solve.

Comment: can you explain in the second line where you went from log(x^logx) = log(x)log(x)

Comment: @user3175999 - Remember that $\log (a^b) = b\log(a)$.

Answer (score 7):

*Hint:* Take the logarithm of both sides. You will get a [quadratic equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation) in $y=\log x$.

Comment: thanks, this helped, but the other person was more clear